# Cannot convert value of type '(Either<NestedType>) -> Void' to expected argument type '(Either<[_]>) -> Void'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, swift4.1

I am trying to use Codable with protocols to handle an API request and response. The API I am querying responds with an array of items under the key "results":

```
{ results: ["id": "1", "id": "2"] }
```

I am therefore looking to construct a nested Codable type.

From the code below, using Items in the completion handler works, but using NestedType or TestResponse does not work and returns the following error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '(Either<NestedType>) -> Void' to expected argument type '(Either<[_]>) -> Void'
```

I am not sure why this does not work. Tried using Swift 4 and Swift 4.1

```
import Foundation

enum Either<T> {
    case success(T)
    case error(Error)
}

enum APIError: Error {
    case unknown, badResponse, jsonDecoder
}

protocol APIClient {
    var session: URLSession { get }
    func get<T: Codable>(with request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (Either<[T]>) -> Void)
}

extension APIClient {

    var session: URLSession {
        return URLSession.shared
    }

    func get<T: Codable>(with request: URLRequest, completion: @escaping (Either<[T]>) -> Void) {

        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            guard error == nil else {
                completion(.error(error!))
                return
            }

            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse, 200..<300 ~= response.statusCode else {
                completion(.error(APIError.badResponse))
                return
            }

            guard let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data!) else {
                completion(.error(APIError.jsonDecoder))
                return
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                completion(.success(value))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}

class TestClient: APIClient {

    func fetch(with endpoint: TestEndpoint, completion: @escaping (Either<NestedType>) -> Void) {
        let request = endpoint.request

        print(request.allHTTPHeaderFields)

        print("endpoint request", endpoint)

        get(with: request, completion: completion)
    }
}

typealias Items = [SingleItem]
typealias NestedType = TestResponse

struct TestResponse: Codable {
    let result: [SingleItem]
}

struct SingleItem: Codable {
    let id: String
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `fetch` method’s completion handler needs to be declared to take an `Either<[NestedType]>`, not an `Either<NestedType>`, because your `get` method requires a completion handler that takes an `Either` of an array.

Incidentally, the type you have called `Either`, we usually call [`Result`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Result.swift).

Comment: That has solved that issue but my completion handler is now failing in a similar way: Member 'success' in 'Result<_>' produces result of type 'Result<T>', but context expects 'Result<_>' -- Are these error messages just a case of passing through the wrong type.

Comment: Ah, it's because I didn't change it from [T].self to T.self I think